# Possible to turn 10 similar functions into a for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to pipe information from my workspaces into another command, and because each workspace contains the same information, with only a different number to identify it, I have written 10 functions where the only difference is one character inside some variable names. I feel like this can be greatly simplified, but I cannot figure out how to get any sort of loop working in my situation.

All here is my script containing the 10 functions:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Include config file.
. $(dirname $0)/config

getWorkspaceInfo(){
    filledWorkspaces=$(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | grep -Po '"'"name"'"\s*:\s*"\K([^"]*)')
    currentWorkspace=$(i3-msg -t get_outputs | sed 's/.*"current_workspace":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
}

# Determine the status of each workspace. Current is green, unfocused is white, empty is grey.
workspace1(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 1 ]]; then
        workspace1Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "1") == "" ]]; then
        workspace1Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace1Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace1Color}}${workspace1Name}"
}

workspace2(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 2 ]]; then
        workspace2Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "2") == "" ]]; then
        workspace2Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace2Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace2Color}}${workspace2Name}"
}

workspace3(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 3 ]]; then
        workspace3Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "3") == "" ]]; then
        workspace3Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace3Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace3Color}}${workspace3Name}"
}

workspace4(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 4 ]]; then
        workspace4Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "4") == "" ]]; then
        workspace4Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace4Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace4Color}}${workspace4Name}"
}

workspace5(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 5 ]]; then
        workspace5Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "5") == "" ]]; then
        workspace5Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace5Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace5Color}}${workspace5Name}"
}

workspace6(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 6 ]]; then
        workspace6Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "6") == "" ]]; then
        workspace6Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace6Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace6Color}}${workspace6Name}"
}

workspace7(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 7 ]]; then
        workspace7Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "7") == "" ]]; then
        workspace7Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace7Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace7Color}}${workspace7Name}"
}

workspace8(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 8 ]]; then
        workspace8Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "8") == "" ]]; then
        workspace8Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace8Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace8Color}}${workspace8Name}"
}

workspace9(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 9 ]]; then
        workspace9Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "9") == "" ]]; then
        workspace9Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace9Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace9Color}}${workspace9Name}"
}

workspace10(){
    if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq 10 ]]; then
        workspace10Color=${green}
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "10") == "" ]]; then
        workspace10Color=${grey}
    else
        workspace10Color=${foreground}
    fi

    echo "%{F${workspace10Color}}${workspace10Name}"
}

# Pipe functions to the bar infinitely.
while true; do
    getWorkspaceInfo
    echo "%{c}$(workspace1)${separator}$(workspace2)${separator}$(workspace3)${separator}$(workspace4)${separator}$(workspace5)${separator}$(workspace6)${separator}$(workspace7)${separator}$(workspace8)${separator}$(workspace9)${separator}$(workspace10)"
done | lemonbar -g ${panelWidth}x${panelHeight}+${panelX}+${bottomPanelY} -f "${font}" -f "${iconFont}" -B "${background}" -F "${foreground}" -p -d  | \
    while true; do read line; eval $line; done &
```

Here is the config file that I am importing:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Outside sources
xres="$HOME/.Xresources"
i3config="$HOME/.config/i3/config"

# Fetch information from Xresources
background=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i background | tail -c 8)
foreground=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i foreground | tail -c 8)
black=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color0 | tail -c 8)
grey=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color8 | tail -c 8)
red=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color9 | tail -c 8)
green=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color10 | tail -c 8)
yellow=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color11 | tail -c 8)
blue=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color12 | tail -c 8)
magenta=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color13 | tail -c 8)
cyan=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color14 | tail -c 8)
white=$(cat ${xres} | grep -i color15 | tail -c 8)

# Fetch information from i3 config
gapSize=$(cat ${i3config} | grep -i "gaps inner" | awk '{print $3}')

# Workspace names -- independant from i3 config -- workspaces in i3 config should be named numbers 1-10.
workspace1Name="Web Browser"
workspace2Name="Terminal"
workspace3Name="Text Editor"
workspace4Name="Unspecified"
workspace5Name="Unspecified"
workspace6Name="Unspecified"
workspace7Name="Unspecified"
workspace8Name="Unspecified"
workspace9Name="Messenger"
workspace10Name="Music Player"

# Fonts
font="InputSans-10"
iconFont="FontAwesome"

separator="%{F$foreground}   |│|   "

# Panel size
screenWidth=$(xrandr | grep 'Screen 0'| awk '{print $8}')
screenHeight=$(xrandr | grep 'Screen 0' | awk '{print $10}' | tr -d ",")

panelHeight=$((${gapSize} * 2))
panelWidth=$((${screenWidth} - ${panelHeight}))
panelX=${gapSize}
topPanelY=${gapSize}
bottomPanelY=$((${screenHeight} - ${panelHeight} - ${gapSize}))
```

Comment: Does your function actually need to set the global variable `workspace1color`? As in -- is there some later code, after the function has been called, that needs to use the `workspace1color` that the function set?

Comment: No, the last line of the script -- which comes after the declaration of all the functions -- simply calls them all and then pipes the output.

Comment: You can save a ton of slow processes avoiding useless uses of `cat`: `red=$(grep -i color9 $xres | tail -c 8)`. Next, `grep|awk` is an *anti-pattern* because awk has grep built in: `xrandr | awk '/Screen 0/ {print $8}'`.

Comment: @Jens, Thank you for the information. I just started using bash -- and Linux for that matter -- so hopefully my usage will get better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the simplest fix is to write something like:

```
function all_10_workspaces () {
    local i
    for i in {1..10} ; do
        local workspaceNameVar="workspace${i}Name"
        local workspaceName="${!workspaceNameVar}"

        local color
        if (( currentWorkspace == 1 )) ; then
            color=$green
        elif grep -w -q "$i" <<< "$filledWorkspaces" ; then
            color=$foreground
        else
            color=$grey
        fi

        echo "%{F$color}$workspaceName"
    done
}
```

. . . however, you should really consider using arrays instead. For example:

```
workspaceNames=(
    ''             # 0 (no such workspace)
    'Web Browser'  # 1
    Terminal       # 2
    'Text Editor'  # 3
    Unspecified    # 4
    Unspecified    # 5
    Unspecified    # 6
    Unspecified    # 7
    Unspecified    # 8
    Messenger      # 9
    'Music Player' # 10
)
```

Then, for example, workspace #7 is named `"${workspaceNames[7]}"`, and given a variable `i`, workspace #*i* is named `"${workspaceNames[i]}"`.

Comment: This works very well, but I must have misunderstood how this function would have turned out. The point of this script is to show the name of each workspace graphically by piping the information to another program. This currently loops through each workspace name and displays them over the last. Thank you for showing me how arrays work, there are many other situations in small scripts that I've written where arrays would have also been useful. I included the entire script rather than one function in my question if I did not disinterest you by asking for the wrong information.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this, you can use `!` to include a variable within a variable? Previously I was just trying to do `${workspace${i}Name}`.

Comment: @Wulfre: If `foo` is a variable whose value is `bar`, then `${!foo}` is equivalent to `${bar}`. This is called *indirect expansion*. See [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: I solved the problem by expanding on both of your ideas -- the for loop and the array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
workspaceCount=10

while true; do
  # Output will look like "%{c}$(workspace1Color)${separator}$(workspace2Color)${separator}...."

  # This is what is sent before the first item in each line
  itemSep="%{c}"

  for i in {1..$workspaceCount}; do

    if [ ${currentWorkspace} -eq $i ]; then
      color="${green}"
    elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "1") == "" ]]; then
      color="${grey}"
    else
      color="${foreground}"
    fi

    echo -n "${itemSep}${color}"
    itemSep="${separator}"

  done
  echo   # Send LF after all items

done
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea on how to make separators work. I stole that idea for my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to get what I wanted using ideas from both ruakh and Phil Freed as well as something I came up with on my own. This may not be the shortest or most efficient way to solve the problem, but it is much shorter than having 10 separate functions.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Include config file.
. $(dirname $0)/config

getWorkspaceInfo(){
    filledWorkspaces=$(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | grep -Po '"'"name"'"\s*:\s*"\K([^"]*)')
    currentWorkspace=$(i3-msg -t get_outputs | sed 's/.*"current_workspace":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/')
}

# Determine the status of each workspace. Current is green, unfocused is white, empty is grey.
workspaces(){
    workspaces=""
    currentSeparator="${separator}"

    for i in {1..10} ; do
        if [[ ${currentWorkspace} -eq ${i} ]]; then
            color=${green}
        elif [[ $(echo ${filledWorkspaces} | grep -w "${i}") == "" ]]; then
            color=${grey}
        else
            color=${foreground}
        fi

        if [[ ${i} -eq 10 ]]; then
            currentSeparator=""
        fi

        workspaces+="%{F$color}${workspaceNames[i]}${currentSeparator}"
    done

    echo "${workspaces}"
}

# Pipe functions to the bar infinitely.
while true; do
    getWorkspaceInfo
    echo "%{c}$(workspaces)"
done | lemonbar -g ${panelWidth}x${panelHeight}+${panelX}+${bottomPanelY} -f "${font}" -f "${iconFont}" -B "${background}" -F "${foreground}" -p -d | \
    while true; do read line; eval $line; done &
```

To explain what it does as simply as possible:
Loop through all 10 workspaces, adding what would have been the output of a single function to the end of a new variable. Since I cannot add a separator between each function call anymore, I simply added the separator to the end of the echo, making sure that no separator is added to the last workspace by using a for loop, which sets the separator variable to null.